# StructOpt: how to combine all arguments in a single string?

Tags: rust, structopt

What I want to do is to access user-provided command-line arguments as a single string.
First, I did this as:

```
let lst: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();
let res: String = lst[1..].join(" ");
```

But then I decided to try doing it with [`structopt`](https://crates.io/crates/structopt) and got stuck. Is it possible to achieve desired result with `structopt` and how should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is simple example:

```rust
extern crate structopt; // 0.3.11

use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
#[structopt(name = "arguments")]
struct Arguments {
    #[structopt(name = "ARGUMENTS")]
    rest: Vec<String>
}

impl Arguments {
    fn get_joined(&self, separator: &str) -> String {
        self.rest.join(separator)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let arguments = Arguments::from_args();

    println!("{}", arguments.get_joined(" "));
}
```

If you just need to join arguments to string, your approach is already good. I suppose you want to use `structopt` because you want to read other command line arguments. In that case, just extend struct to support `key=value` pairs. For example:

```rust
extern crate structopt; // 0.3.11

use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
#[structopt(name = "arguments")]
struct Arguments {
    #[structopt(short, long)]
    debug: bool,

    #[structopt(short = "v", long = "velocity", default_value = "42")]
    speed: f64,

    #[structopt(name = "ARGUMENTS")]
    rest: Vec<String>
}

impl Arguments {
    fn get_joined(&self, separator: &str) -> String {
        self.rest.join(separator)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let arguments = Arguments::from_args();

    println!("{}", arguments.get_joined(" "));

    println!("{:?}", arguments);
}
```

Call should looks like: `./target/release/try-structopt --debug -v 9.81 who am i`

And the output is:

`who am i`

`Arguments { debug: true, speed: 9.81, rest: ["who", "am", "i"] }`